# Downloading Future Worlclim data at 0.5 resolution

Tags: r, file, raster, r-raster, geotiff

I need to download future bioclim variables at 0.5 minute (30 second) resolution from Worldclim. I can use the code `getData` function to download it at a lower resolution, but not the higher resolution I need.

Downloading the file directly from the website https://www.worldclim.org/data/cmip6/cmip6_clim30s.html#google_vignette leaves me with an inaccessible GeoTIFF file, i.e. when I open it in R the "names" only has the name of the GeoTIFF file, where it should have the name of each variable (e.g. "bio_6").

Does anyone know either how to load this file into R so that I can extract each variable OR how to download it directly to R?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

To access the CMIP6 data, you can use `geodata::cmip6_world` or `geodata::cmip6_tile`.